# SVG path is different after morphing with Animejs

Tags: javascript, svg, clip-path, animejs, svg-morphing

I was trying to morph a clip-path from 1 shape to another using anime.js. The shapes have an identical number of points.

I ran into some issues with the paths not correctly showing. Upon further inspection I found that when I tried to animate the `d` property of a `path` using anime.js, the outcome in the DOM would be different than what I passed in the anime.js animation function.

[I built a simple codepen to show the issue.](https://codepen.io/TristanFKirwan/pen/dygbLzM).

Initially, the image is clipped using the path with id `path`, which has a `d` attribute equal to:

`M-82.511-84.642a.483.483,0,0,1,.174.226.45.45,0,0,1-.061.259.677.677,0,0,1-.14.222.467.467,0,0,1-.251.112.572.572,0,0,1-.314-.041.377.377,0,0,1-.224-.226.617.617,0,0,1,.072-.326.8.8,0,0,1,.158-.3.366.366,0,0,1,.305-.1A.621.621,0,0,1-82.511-84.642Z`

Then, when you click the button, the `anime` function runs on the path and tries to change it to the same value.

That anime function is as follows:

```
anime({
  targets: 'svg path',
  duration: 500,
  easing: 'linear',
  d: 'M-82.511-84.642a.483.483,0,0,1,.174.226.45.45,0,0,1-.061.259.677.677,0,0,1-.14.222.467.467,0,0,1-.251.112.572.572,0,0,1-.314-.041.377.377,0,0,1-.224-.226.617.617,0,0,1,.072-.326.8.8,0,0,1,.158-.3.366.366,0,0,1,.305-.1A.621.621,0,0,1-82.511-84.642Z'
})
```

I have also tried the following, as it is closer to the code that is shown in the anime.js documentation:

```
anime({
  targets: 'svg path',
  duration: 500,
  easing: 'linear',
  d: [{ value: "M-82.511-84.642a.483.483,0,0,1,.174.226.45.45,0,0,1-.061.259.677.677,0,0,1-.14.222.467.467,0,0,1-.251.112.572.572,0,0,1-.314-.041.377.377,0,0,1-.224-.226.617.617,0,0,1,.072-.326.8.8,0,0,1,.158-.3.366.366,0,0,1,.305-.1A.621.621,0,0,1-82.511-84.642Z"}]
})
```

However, as you can see visually, the svg is nowehere near what it was. Inspecting the path shows that the `d` attribute that should be the same before and after the animation is no longer the same. It is now:

`M-82.511 -84.642a0,0,1,0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 -0.314 0.377,0,0,1 -0.224 0.617,0,0,1,0.072 0.8,0,0,1,0.158 0.366,0,0,1,0.305 -0.1A0,0,1 -82.511 -84.642Z`.

As I said, this is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. The anime.js documentation doesn't explicitly mention being able to animate the `d` attribute, but seeing as it does actually change the path, I would imagine this should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, anime.js has a **bug parsing highly minified path data** strings.

Probably, the parsing **regex** should be improved to handle concatenated floating point values like

```
a.483.483,0,0,1,.174.226.45.45,0,0,1-.061.259
```

translates to

```
a .483 .483 0 0 1 .174 .226
.45 .45 0 0 1 -.061 .259
```

But gets parsed as `a0,0,1,0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1`

### Workaround: "deminify" your path data e.g with [svg path editor.](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)

Paste you `d` string and click the **minify** checkbox twice.

#### Result:

```
M -82.511 -84.642 a 0.483 0.483 0 0 1 0.174 0.226 a 0.45 0.45 0 0 1 -0.061 0.259 a 0.677 0.677 0 0 1 -0.14 0.222 a 0.467 0.467 0 0 1 -0.251 0.112 a 0.572 0.572 0 0 1 -0.314 -0.041 a 0.377 0.377 0 0 1 -0.224 -0.226 a 0.617 0.617 0 0 1 0.072 -0.326 a 0.8 0.8 0 0 1 0.158 -0.3 a 0.366 0.366 0 0 1 0.305 -0.1 A 0.621 0.621 0 0 1 -82.511 -84.642 Z
```